# Install Php and asp on the same iis

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, webserver

I need to install php.

Can i install php on iis that include already asp.net and asp core sites?

Can asp and php run together on the same web server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It’s possible. PHP is cross platform meaning it can run both on Windows and Linux. So, with a Windows Server you can easily run PHP and ASP.NET. Don’t forget to choose different ports and configure them

Comment: Thanks Sajjad. For what reason do i need different ports? Each site has his own domain or subdomain.

Comment: recommended but not necessary. If you are using IIS Configure IIS for asp.net Then register your php engine with IIS server